# error while loading shared libraries: libCstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, netbeans, memory-leaks, sunstudio

error while loading shared libraries: libCstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Hello! I got this error when I tried to run a C++ project in Netbeans 6.8 with the Sun compiler from Sun Studio 12.1. I want analyze memory leaks and memory usage with dbx or the NetBeans IDE if it retrieves needed information. As I don't know about debugging... Do you think to use Netbeans+Sun Studio is the correct way to perform C++ applications? I used Netbeans on Windows but I don't know about free memory leaks detection tools on Windows and I tried Sun Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Sun's compiler but when you see that error, it's usually because the location of the library in question is not in any path registered with the shared library loader. This can usually be fixed by adding the path in question to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then running `ldconfig`.