# Netbeans: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.50: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, timezone, shared-libraries, netbeans-7, icu

I'm trying to use the ICU-Timezone API with Netbeans c++(7.3) under Ubuntu with.

I have added the Librarys and include directory for ICU.

Then I want to execute this simple example code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DateFormats.h"
#include "NumberFormats.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <timezone.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    TimeZone *tz = TimeZone::createTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");  
}
```

I get the Error

> /home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/DFC/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/dfc: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.50: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Hope you can help me!

Thanks
Florian

Comment: Is the shared object file exist on your system? is it on correct path such that it can be found?

Comment: Project Properties > Build > Linker > Libraries I have added a few libraries, also libicuuc.so. Do I have to add libicuuc.so.50 seperately?

Comment: now I have the same error with "libicui18n.so.50" what are those .50 files?

Comment: .50 is the version number, see here: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#AEN46

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561742/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libcstd-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-fi)

Comment: great to know that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run followed command is fine

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

or you can use vi to add to file permanently

`vi ~/.bashrc`